# Software Engineer not programming in the job. Should I quit?

Tags: career-development, careers

I am working on a very inventive and bleeding-edge startup, in the exact position that I want to be in terms of company and compensation. However, I didn't write a lot of code in the past year since I am the "support guy" (customer-success role), which feels contra-productive to my career given how I have a CS degree and always worked on engineering.

- Should I quit my job and pursue another position that lets me code?
- Who can I talk to about this dilemma? Friends and family can't see past the shiny brand nor the compensation.
- Is it possible to move from a support role to engineering if I persist in my job?

Thanks in advance for all the answers.

*PS: Couldn't write specifics due to off-topic concerns*

Comment: What sort of tasks *have* you been doing for the last year given that you "haven't released anything or programmed at all"?

Comment: This question is probably going to get closed as off topic, but if you wish to reach out, my email is in my profile, and I could probably steer you in the right direction.

Everything in the strictest confidence, of course

Comment: @PlayerOne I basically assist our users to get used to the platform. I am also a bridge between the team and the customer regarding issues, problems and that type of stuff.

Comment: @RichardU That is really sad, tbh. I have checked https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110852/where-can-you-ask-about-career-advice and other resources...

Comment: @RichardU Thanks for offering me your contact. I think I will reach out to you, depending on how this question goes.

Comment: @anon_pgd there was a proposal to have such a site on Area 51, but it got killed quickly, I used to teach classes on the subject, so I was a bit miffed that the idea was shut down.

Comment: @anon_pgd - you may find that the question gets reopened if you can make some edits based on the description for the close reason (in the yellow box immediately above the comments here).

Comment: @dwizum Oh yes, I think I can do it later today. Thank once again!

Comment: @dwizum What do you think?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You asked several related questions. Unfortunately, they're all fairly hard for *us* to answer directly, because they are fairly personal choices. Ultimately, you need to decide what is important to you in a job - both in the short term sense:

- Are you happy with the work in front of you? Is it fulfilling?
- Do you like your coworkers, your boss, your company?
- Is the salary sufficient for your financial needs?

and in the long term sense:

- Does this position "fit" in your overall career?
- Will this position help you get where you want to go next?
- Does the company operate in a way that will help you get there?

For different people, the answers to these questions will be different. Some people will be happy doing work they don't like if it gets them lots of money, or if it is an obvious stepping-stone to a job they really want. Other people will only be happy if they are coding in a specific language, or working with specific tools. Others will only be happy if they're given "creative freedom" in their work. And so on.

You seem a little hung up on the fact that you're not developing. That, in and of itself, isn't inherently a good thing or a bad thing. Many successful, happy people started out thinking they would be developers, but then took their careers in a different direction, because they found they were happy doing other work, or good at other work. Often, crossing over from one role to another like this can be a good thing, even if you decide to return to your first career path, because it gives you a perspective you may not have had if you had remained 100% a pure "developer."

So - reflect on what is important to you, and answer your own questions. Determine your goals, see how your current job fits against those goals, and make a plan based on what you find.

Comment: I truly appreciate your answer, @dwizum.

Comment: I would add just one more question: Does this coincide with your carrier goals, where do you see yourself in 5 years?

Comment: @strader That is a little trickier. I don't see myself in a support role at all. However, if this position can put me on engineering (where I was before), then it is indeed aligned. Here is the deal, there is a huge gap in customer success in our company and I am also doing it to see our business succeed. But I fear if this will bring my career to a path where I "lost" 2 years instead of evolving. I don't know, it is a really tough position.

Comment: @anon_pgd IMHO, this particular excursion can get you to more management / lead position when simply development job. And for the case of "loosing" time - buzzword title can offset it in case positional advancement would not happen

Comment: New software engineers often get hung up on feeling like they are some how "losing" if they are not always chasing the current shiny object in terms of tech stack. Don't fall into that trap! Some of the most brilliant, successful, happy, and well compensated developers I know are experts in languages that have probably been around since before you were born.

Comment: Hey @dwizum, here is the thing... My company focuses heavily on OSS and we are known as "cool guys" in the industry. So we are the ones producing shiny objects on bleeding edge tech. Not being able to contribute to our product and code it is kinda a bummer for me. But I do get your point and I see how I need to work on my thinking about this topic. Thank you for the comment!

Comment: No matter what happens, do not discard a learning opportunity simply because you are focused elsewhere. Even if you decide to pursue programming, consider the benefit of having been directly exposed to customers, and how that can give you a perspective that will be useful when you are developing.

Comment: Thanks! I certainly see the value in it now...

Comment: @anon_pgd You are welcome

Answer (score 2):

> Do I have a chance to transition from a support role to engineering if I stay in the company? Meaning, how often a company will give the opportunity to "the support guy"?

I've known several people who have made a transition from support to a development role. Basically, you want to start by letting your manager know that you have a degree in computer science and would like the opportunity to switch to a development role. You should ask your manager what opportunities exist and when you might get a chance to do that.

You can, at the same time, see what opportunities you can get on the open market. That should help you compare your options of how to get into a development role fastest.

> Should I quit and pursue a job that I can code?
>   Should I just do a job because of the wage?

This forum isn't good for answering "should I" questions.

> What people can I talk to that could understand my position and give me advice? Friends and family are kinda biased and they don't see past the shine of the "brand" and the "compensation".

If possible, try to find someone who can be your mentor. Often, people find mentors from among their professional relationships. You want to seek someone who both knows you and understands the industry sufficiently to give helpful advice.